# What is the difference between "ĵaluzi" and "envii"?

Tags: verbs

I have been using *ĵaluzi* and *envii* interchangeably, but recently I saw some comments in a chat goup about it. One person corrected another, saying it should be *ĵaluzi* and not *envii*. I now suppose there is a difference. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://vortaro.net/#%C4%B5aluza

*Ĵaluza*

"*Sentanta doloran maltrankvilon pro la timo pri perdo aŭ difekto de iu sia posedaĵo*"

"Feeling a painful uneasiness from the fear of loss or failure of a possession"

http://vortaro.net/#envia

*Envii*

"1 *Deziri havi tion, kion alia posedas*"

"The desire to have what another haves"

"2 *Senti malĝojon k malamon kontraŭ iu, kiu posedas ion, kion oni mem malhavas*"

"To feel sadness and hatred for someone who possesses something which you yourself don't (or can't) have."

Comment: Cxu tio estas via klarigo, aux la fonto ekzistas ie en la reto?

Comment: Kaj mia klarigo kaj tio de PIV. Mi aldonis la ligilojn al PIV.

Comment: I think "painful" would be a better translation for "*doloran*" than "hurtful".

Comment: Hmm, I like that better. Edited!

Answer (score 7):

The difference between the two english words, *jealousy* and *envy*, is well explained [in the Simpsons](http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/apoY335_700b.jpg)

> Jealousy is when you worry that someone will take what you have. Envy is wanting what someone else has.

*ĵaluzi* and *envii* are the esperanto versions of these concepts, so *ĵaluzi* is fearing someone will take what you have, and *envii* is wanting something someone else has.

Comment: Although this is correct, I think it’s a little misleading because in English _jealous_ is also commonly used to mean _envious_, as in “I’m jealous of your ice cream”. I think in Esperanto it would be wrong to use _ĵaluzi_ in this case.

Comment: @NeilRoberts that is a good point. It seems like *jealous* has evolved to also be a synonym for *envious* over time, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jealousy)

Answer (score 2):

According to PIV the root [*ĵaluz/*](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%B5aluz) has an adjective character, i.e. the adjective *ĵaluza* is the first entry. There are listed two definitions:

1. the one with feeling an uneasiness of loosing something

   *Mi estas **ĵaluza pri** mia reputacio* : I am nervous about my
   reputation.
2. the second one of feeling jealous of a loved one

   *Mi estas/sentas min **ĵaluza pri** mia edzino* : I feel jealous of my wife.

However for the verb *ĵaluzi* only one definition is given: *konduti ĵaluze* in the second sense of the root. So I read this to mean, that one can say *Mi ĵaluzas pri mia edzino*, but not **Mi ĵaluzas pri mia reputacio** (reword to *Mi estas sentema pri mia reputacio*).

On the other hand [*envi/*](http://vortaro.net/#envi) has a verbal character with two definitions:

1. the one with a desire to have what another has (*envii **ion al iu***)
2. the second one with feeling sadness for someone having something what you don't have (*envii **iun pro io***). This second definition is related to *ĵaluzi*.

To complete the analysis the adjective *envia* is related to the noun *envio*, which to my reading can have both meanings of the verbal root.